# get url not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on the following code that is pulling information from a DB.

This is what i want the code to do:

- A user logs in.
- If the image belongs to the user, after the db is queried only this image requested and found by the query that belongs to the user must show up.
- if the image number requested does not belong to the user, the page must either error out or redirect.

This is the code:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_GET['uid']); // get user ref #
$imgid = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_GET['img']); // get img ref #
$query = mysql_query("SELECT mypage.*, img.* 
                      FROM img 
                      JOIN mypage ON img.user = mypage.user WHERE mypage.id = '$id'");

if ((mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)) {    
  header("location:page.php?uid=$id");      
  die(mysql_error());
} else { 
  while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $img = $rows['img'];
    $pfname = $rows['pfname'];
    $plname = $rows['plname'];
    $puser = $rows['puser'];
    $description = $rows['description'];
    $ppid_image_name = $rows['ppid_image_name'];
  }
```

When I run the code, I am able to print out the correct result. The problem is the get URL part.

Let's say the URL is `http://www/profile.php?uid=5&img=4...` img=4, the referenced image belongs to the user, so yes, this image shows up when call.
If img=5, this referenced image does not belong but yet it shows up under the user, but not when i query the result.
If img=12, a ref image number that does not exists in the DB, I get an error instead of a redirect.

I seem to be mostly having problems with the conocation part of the url. `&img=ref#`

I'm not sure if the problm is here: `if ((mysql_num_rows($query)==0))`.
I tried `if ((mysql_num_rows($query)!=imgid)) redirect`, this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There is an error in your query , Use Left Join instead of Join

```
mysql_query("SELECT mypage.*, img.* 
                        FROM img 
                        LEFT JOIN mypage ON img.user = mypage.user WHERE mypage.id = '$id'");
```

2) Test this :

```
  while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $img = $rows['img'];
    $pfname = $rows['pfname'];
    $plname = $rows['plname'];
    $puser = $rows['puser'];
    $description = $rows['description'];
    $ppid_image_name = $rows['ppid_image_name'];
}
if (!isset($img)) {    
  header("location:page.php?uid=$id");      
  die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: . thanks for your help, but when tried it threw off the result, if the user does not have an img it will not show up their name

Comment: i put $img for example!replace it by field what have a valid value all time!

Comment: trying a different approach, seems to work partially $id = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_GET['uid']); // get user ref #
$imgid = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_GET['img']); // get img ref #
$query = mysql_query("SELECT mypage.*, img.* 
                      FROM img 
                      JOIN mypage ON img.user = mypage.user WHERE mypage.id = '$id'");

if($imgid != $image) echo "foo"; // compare the geturl vid to field image {    
else echo "bar";   if a put a  ref # that is not found in the query it works for some but not for all. why?

Comment: You wanna fetch from 2 tables use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN